# Confused about .Net socket lifecycle

Tags: .net, sockets

I'm confused about the .Net Socket lifecycle, especially on the closing end.   According to the MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)  Sockets can do a *BeginDisconnect(), Disconnect(), Shutdown(), Close()* and *Finalize()*.    But I'm a little confused about when I would choose to do each of these, and which ones send FIN, which ones send RST, which ones prevent new events from calling my event handler, etc.  Also, since *Close()* releases the socket's resources, when would I need to do a *Finalize()* separately?

My question was raised because I had been doing a

```
      if (_TCPConn.Connected)
      {
          _TCPConn.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
          _TCPConn.Disconnect(true); 
      }
```

(_TCPConn was my socket) and as soon as I did the *Disconnect()* I was getting

> A request to send or receive data was disallowed because the socket
> had already been shut down in that direction with a previous shutdown
> call

...in my event handler, because data was still coming in asynchronously and triggering the handler.    Doing a *Close()* appears to be the solution to this. But that's when I realized I needed to understand this better.    Also, what are the symmetrical methods for bringing the socket back to life from these different methods of stopping it?

A good answer to this question would be if someone could point out a good article or resource describing the .Net socket lifecycle.

Answer (score 0):

You're confusing a few things here.  BeginDisconnect is the asynchronous (won't block your thread) version of Disconnect.  So which one you use depends on if you're ok with blocking your thread until the Disconnect is complete.

Shutdown must be called on connection oriented sockets before you call close.  It doesn't seem to be needed on non-connection oriented sockets.

Close and Dispose are equivalent.  You should call either one when you're no longer in need of the socket and its ok to release the resources it holds.

You never call Finalize; that is done by the GC in the event you don't properly Dispose of your socket.  But that is not unique to sockets, anything that implements IDisposable functions the same way.  MS also recommends creating a method called Close if that's more intuitive than Dispose would be (files and sockets can be Opened, so it makes sense that they can be Closed).  However with the addition of the using statement I rarely  use the explicitly Close methods anymore.

I suggest you read up more on using [IDisposable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/498928w2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I'm not sure anything will send a reset; I would think FIN would be sent on Close / Dispose.